# Performance Issue with Doctrine, PostGIS and MapFish

Tags: performance, symfony1, doctrine, openlayers, postgis

I am developing a WebGIS application using Symfony with the MapFish plugin http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfMapFishPlugin

I use the GeoJSON produced by MapFish to render layers through OpenLayers, in a vector layer of course.

When I show layers up to 3k features everything works fine. When I try with layers with 10k features or more the application crash. I don't know the threshold, because I either have layers with 2-3k features or with 10-13k features.

I think the problem is related with doctrine, because the last report in the log is something like:

```
Sep 02 13:22:40 symfony [info] {Doctrine_Connection_Statement} execute :
```

and then the query to fetch the geographical records.

I said I think the problem is the number of features. So I used the OpenLayers.Strategy.BBox() to decrease the number of feature to get and to show. The result is the same. The app seems stuck while executing the query.

If I add a limit to the query string used to get the features' GeoJSON the application works. So I don't think this is related to the MapFish plugin but with Doctrine.

Anyone has some enlightenment?
Thanks!

Comment: I have just tried with a super zoomed scale and... surprise! The features are displayed!
That's cool because I can work on my application, but that don't solve the performance issue when there's the necessity of loading more than 3k records.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if theorically possible, it’s a bad idea to try to show so many vector features on a map.
You'd better change the way features are displayed (eg. raster for low zoom levels, get feature on click…).

Even if your service answer in a reasonable time, your browser will be stuck, or at least  will have very bad performance…
I’m the author of sfMapFishPlugin and I never ever tried to query so many features, and even less tried to show them on a OL map.

Check out OpenLayers FAQ on this subject: http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#WhatisthemaximumnumberofCoordinatesFeaturesIcandrawwithaVectorlayer , a bit outdated with recent browsers improvements, but 10k vector features on a map *is not* reasonable.

HTH,

Comment: Thanks! I agree with you, it's not thinkable to show such a lot of features. Anyway my doubt regarding Doctrine performances remains...

Comment: You can try calling your service with curl, playing with the `limit` parameter and see if there’s a real problem. Or an `explain analyse` in postgres to find the bottleneck.